# Moments table for Johnson SU distribution reference request

Tags: probability, distributions, references, moments, parameterization

The Johnson SU distribution has 4 shape parameters ($\delta,\gamma,\lambda,\beta$). Below shows the range of skewness and kurtosis values that can be attained using the Johnson SU distribution (SU). What's absent is how to actually *set* the 4 parameters of the distribution in order to obtain a specific moments configuration for mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis ($\mu, \sigma^2, \xi, \kappa$).

[image]

Instead of

- manually using the Johnson SU distribution's known formulas for its
  moments, which show them to be functions of the parameters,
- or using the Johnson moments distribution [algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2346692.pdf) by Hill et al (1976) which doesn't make much sense

has anyone instead laid out in **a statistical table** how parameter configurations correspond to target moments for this distribution?

$$\delta,\gamma,\lambda,\beta \Longrightarrow \mu, \sigma^2, \xi, \kappa$$

#### Closest reference match

In the Hill algorithm article, they write

> This algorithm supplements Tables 34, 35 and 36 of Pearson and Hartley (1972), for SU and SB curves.

> Pearson, E. S. and Hartley, H. O. (1972). *Biometrika Tables for
> Statisticians*, Vol. 2. Cambridge: University Press.

but I don't have access to that text in order to see if the tables are what I'm looking for. Is anyone else [able to view](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/bimj.19740160412) it?

Comment: How come the algorithm does not make much sense?

Comment: because why would an iterative optimization procedure be required given that each moment configuration is already known to be a function of a specific parameter configuration. Shouldn't we just be able to plug in parameter values into the moment formulas and map out all possible configurations in a statistical table as done with the Fleishman (1978) non-normal-transformation tables?

Comment: Why construct a table if you have Johnson SU distribution's known formulas for its moments as functions of the parameters? Given the formulas, you can easily construct a table yourself, picking the range and grid fineness as you please. Who looks up tables of Normal, Student-$t$ or $F$-distributions routinely included in older statistics textbooks any longer when we have very simple functions in R, Python etc. for obtaining these values?

Comment: I guess thats the point of the question, instead of me making the table, is the table already out there?

Comment: @RichardHardy Here I try to map the moments of its parameters, and find that the `johnsonsu` function is incapable of producing positive skewness https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567759/why-doesnt-johnson-su-distribution-give-positive-skewness-in-scipy-stats